# How to display an array data in a single line for CDetailView

Tags: arrays, yii

The code:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
            'tag',  // problem here
   ),
));
```

If there is an array in the attribute "tag" in this model ($model->tag), how can I display all items in the array?

The attribute 'tag' has an array like this:

```
$model->tag = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

I want this result:

Tag: A, B, C, D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
 'data'=>$model,
 'attributes'=>array(
        array(
            'name'=>'tag',
            'type'=>'text',
            'value'=>implode(", " , $model->tag)
        )// 'tag',
 ),
));
```

Read more about [CDetailView attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#attributes-detail), and php's [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Hope this helps.

Comment: ask for clarifications if needed.